# Salesforce OAuth Flow locale?

Tags: oauth, identity, open-id-connect

Trying to authenticate to a Salesforce community org (External Identity License) from an external application using OpenID / OAuth 2.0. Can the OAuth flow accept a language parameter in the header or url and render a translated screen? How? I can't find anything in the documentation.

I believe I could do something custom if I roll my own OAuth endpoint and drop a language cookie from a passed parameter but looking for an OOB solution for standard oAuth? Anybody have any experience or can help?

What I could find by googling was

1. Twitter uses lang=de_DE
2. Facebook uses locale=es_ES
3. No mention of lang or locale in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
4. OpenID Connect has ui_locales http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-standard-1_0-21.html
5. I can't find anything on Salesforce's documentation about oAuth and lang support

If it's not supported what is the standard?

Comment: Hi @Fitz, did you get an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main login page uses the [`Accept-Language`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) HTTP header to determine the language to use, while the OAuth authorization page uses the user's language setting, since, by then, we know who the user is.

For example, if you go through an OAuth flow with a French browser, but English user record, login is French, and OAuth authorization is English.